# Android RecyclerView item click not working - MVVM

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel

The RecyclerView is showing all data, but the item click is not working. Here I am attaching what I have done so far. For better understanding I am removing all the unnecessary code.

This is my recyclerview item xml.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="model"
        type="com.xyz.abc.pojo.EmployeeListWithDesignationSetGet" />

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.xyz.abc.viewmodels.EmpListWithDesigViewModel" />

</data>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.itemClick(model)}">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_show_details"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Show"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The ViewModel class where I have written the click method.

```
public class EmpListWithDesigViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<List<EmployeeListWithDesignationSetGet>> mutableLiveData;
private EmpListWithDesigClickListener listener;
private EmpListWithDesigRepository empListWithDesigRepository;

public void setListener(EmpListWithDesigClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void init() {
    if (mutableLiveData != null) {
        return;
    }
    empListWithDesigRepository = EmpListWithDesigRepository.getInstance();
    mutableLiveData = empListWithDesigRepository.getEmpList();
}

public MutableLiveData<List<EmployeeListWithDesignationSetGet>> getEmpList() {
    return mutableLiveData;
}

public void itemClick(EmployeeListWithDesignationSetGet employeeListWithDesignationSetGet) {
    listener.onItemClick(employeeListWithDesignationSetGet);
}
}
```

Now in activity I am implementing the click interface.

```
public class EmployeeDesignationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EmpListWithDesigClickListener {

private RecyclerView mRv_recyclerView;
private List<EmployeeListWithDesignationSetGet> arrayList;
private EmployeeListWithDesigAdapter employeeListWithDesigAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employee_designation);

    setViewReferences();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    employeeListWithDesigAdapter = new EmployeeListWithDesigAdapter(this,arrayList);
    mRv_recyclerView.setAdapter(employeeListWithDesigAdapter);

    EmpListWithDesigViewModel empListWithDesigViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(EmpListWithDesigViewModel.class);
    empListWithDesigViewModel.setListener(this);
    empListWithDesigViewModel.init();
    empListWithDesigViewModel.getEmpList().observe(this, new Observer<List<EmployeeListWithDesignationSetGet>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<EmployeeListWithDesignationSetGet> employeeListWithDesignationSetGets) {
            arrayList.addAll(employeeListWithDesignationSetGets);
            employeeListWithDesigAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private void setViewReferences(){
    mRv_recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_activity_employee_designation);
}



@Override
public void onItemClick(EmployeeListWithDesignationSetGet employeeListWithDesignationSetGet) {
    String phone = employeeListWithDesignationSetGet.getEmpPhone();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" +  phone));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Pardon me if I have not provided enough info, this is my first SO post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. I forgot to bind the viewmodel in recyclerview adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `android:onClick="@{() -viewModel.itemClick(model)}"` from `Linearlayout`. Also add the below properties.

```
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Then your item layout will be as below:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_show_details"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Show"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why should I remove the android:onClick="@{() -viewModel.itemClick(model)}"?